# Use concatenation and stringizing in the same macro with GCC

Tags: c, gcc, macros, concatenation, stringification

Those macros are compiled without error with visual studio and codewarrior compilers. With gcc the error is shown in the comment

```
#define STRINGIFY(x)  #x
#define MYINC(n)      STRINGIFY(extensions/##n##/myinc.h)


#include "extensions/1/myinc.h"          // OK (no surprise)
#include STRINGIFY(extensions/1/myinc.h) // OK
#include MYINC(1)                        // error: pasting "1" and "/" does not give a valid preprocessing token
```

Some idea?

Comment: Try getting rid of the second ## in the MYINC definition. You only want to paste parameter 'n'... (Just my guess...)

Comment: @Fe203. No, concatenation needs ## to concatenate left and ## to concatenate right part also

Answer (score 0):

Actually On my environment (WSL2 gcc9.3), the line

```
#include STRINGIFY(extensions/1/myinc.h)
```

event triger compiling error

```
test1.c:6:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
    6 | #include STRINGIFY(extensions/1/myinc.h) // OK
      |          ^~~~~~~~~
test1.c:7:17: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
    7 | #include MYINC(1)
```

From GCC document https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Include-Syntax.html I found this:

> The argument of ‘#include’, whether delimited with quote marks or angle brackets, behaves like a string constant in that comments are not recognized, and macro names are not expanded. Thus, #include <x/*y> specifies inclusion of a system header file named x/*y.

And MSVC-170 document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/preprocessor/hash-include-directive-c-cpp?view=msvc-170 says:

> You can organize constant and macro definitions into include files (also known as header files) and then use #include directives to add them to any source file.

So I guess the problem is some gcc won't expand macro. But if I define:

```
#define INCFILE "extensions/1/myinc.h"
#include INCFILE
```

GCC didn't report error. And If I write:

```
#define INCFILE "extensions/1/myinc.h"
#include STRINGIFY(INCFILE)
```

GCC also reports:

```
test1.c:5:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or <FILENAME>
    5 | #include STRINGIFY(INCFILE) // OK
```

Comment: I tried on WSL1 and gcc 7.5.0 

#include STRINGIFY(extensions/1/myinc.h)

 works fine.